# Return the new rowId when a new row is added to the Room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

When I read the documentation from [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience-insert), it states:

> If the @Insert method receives a single parameter, **it can return a
> long value**, which is the **new rowId** for the inserted item.

This is exactly what I need! When a new row is inserted, I want to return the new rowId and use it in the activity. However I can't get this to work in my current setup (especially in combinations with suspend functions).

**Room Entity**

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "note_table",
    indices = [Index(
        value = ["db_key"],
        unique = true
    )]
)
data class NoteEntity(
    ...
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "db_key")
    val uid: Long? = null
)
```

**Dao**

```
@Dao
interface NoteEntityDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertNote(note: Note)
    ...
}
```

**Repository**

```
interface NoteRepository {

    suspend fun insertNote(note: Note)
    ...
}
```

**Repository Implementation**

```
class NoteRepositoryImplementation @Inject constructor(
    private val dao: NoteEntityDao
) : NoteRepository {

    override suspend fun insertNote(note: NoteEntity) {
        dao.insertNoteEntry(note)
    }
```

**Use Case**

```
class AddNoteUseCase(
    private val repository: NoteRepository
) {

    suspend fun execute(note: Note) {
        repository.insertNote(note)
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class NoteViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val noteUseCases: NoteUseCases
) : ViewModel() {

    fun insertNote(note: NoteEntity) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            noteUseCases.addNoteUseCase.execute(note)
        }
    }
```

**Activity**

```
class NoteActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
...
val newNoteEntry = NoteEntity(
                    title = title,
                    description = description,
                    createdOn = createdOn,
                    createdBy = createdBy
                )

viewModel.insertNote(newNoteEntry)
...
}
```

---

**Solution from Tenfour04:**

**Dao**

```
@Dao
interface NoteEntityDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertNote(note: Note): Long
    ...
}
```

**Repository**

```
interface NoteRepository {

    suspend fun insertNote(note: Note): Long
    ...
}
```

**Repository Implementation**

```
class NoteRepositoryImplementation @Inject constructor(
    private val dao: NoteEntityDao
) : NoteRepository {

    override suspend fun insertNote(note: NoteEntity): Long {
        return dao.insertNoteEntry(note)
    }
...
}
```

**Use Case**

```
class AddNoteUseCase(
    private val repository: NoteRepository
) {

    suspend fun execute(note: Note): Long {
        return repository.insertNote(note)
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class NoteViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val noteUseCases: NoteUseCases
) : ViewModel() {

    suspend fun insertNote(note: NoteEntity): Long {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            return noteUseCases.addNoteUseCase.execute(note)
        }
    }
...
}
```

**Activity**

```
class NoteActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
...
val newNoteEntry = NoteEntity(
                    title = title,
                    description = description,
                    createdOn = createdOn,
                    createdBy = createdBy
                )

lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
                    val foo = viewModel.insertNote(newNoteEntry)
                    Log.d(TAG, "newRowId: $foo")
                }
...
}
```

**Logcat**
[image: Logcat output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DAO, you just need to add a Long return type to the function signature:

```
suspend fun insertNote(note: Note): Long
```

And you can add it in your repository function and so on.

Comment: I tried that but how do I access it in my activity?

Comment: Change your ViewModel’s function to be a suspend function that does *not* launch a coroutine but does return the Long. Call it in your activity in a coroutine launched from `lifecycleScope`.

Comment: Hi Tenfour04, not sure why did not work earlier when I tried the same but maybe it was time for me to sleep :). Thanks for the answer, see solution code above if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

**Dao**

```
@Dao
interface NoteEntityDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertNote(note: Note) : Long
}
```

**Repository Implementation**

class NoteRepositoryImplementation @Inject constructor(
private val dao: NoteEntityDao
) : NoteRepository {

```
override suspend fun insertNote(note: NoteEntity):Long {
    return dao.insertNoteEntry(note)
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class NoteViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val noteUseCases: NoteUseCases
) : ViewModel() {
    private val noteChannelFlow = Channel<NoteEvent>()
    val noteEvent = noteChannelFlow.receiveAsFlow()
    
    fun insertNote(note: NoteEntity) = viewModelScope.launch {
        noteChannelFlow.send(NoteEvent.Inserted(noteUseCases.addNoteUseCase.execute(note)))
    }
    sealed class NoteEvent {
        data class Inserted(val data: Long) : NoteEvent()
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
class NoteActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   ...
   lifecycle.coroutineScope.launchWhenStarted {
       viewModel.noteEvent.collect { event ->

        when(event){
          Log.d("DATA",event.data)
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Samsad, this seems interesting as well. I shall dive more into the topic of Coroutines and Events later. For now, the solution from Tenfour04 works.